# Laravel Breeze without Inertia

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I working on laravel 10 project and I want install authentication starter kit but `php artisan breeze:install vue` install also `inertia` 
How I can install `Laravel Breeze` without installing `inertia` ?

Comment: Inertia should only be installed if you're using Breeze with Vue/React, if you're using blade templates it shouldn't be used. From the docs - "Laravel Breeze's *default view layer* is made up of simple Blade templates styled with Tailwind CSS. Or, Breeze can scaffold your application using Vue or React and Inertia."

Comment: @AndyHolmes OK , there is a way now to cancel this command `php artisan breeze:install vue` and go back to previous version ?? I don't use git yet

Comment: Just delete the files from vendor etc. and install it fresh, you'd be better off getting up and running with git sooner than later so you can easily roll back

Comment: Delete vendor folder. Remove `laravel/breeze` from `composer.json`. Run `composer install` and then run `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` and `php artisan breeze:install` without the `vue` part!

Comment: @geertjanknapen Can I run `composer remove laravel/breeze` without deleting vendor folder ?

Comment: @MAHAOUEGHLANI You can but that won't remove the files the `php artisan breeze:install` has created, therefore not 'fully' deleting the Inertia stuff. Best to just delete vendor folder.

Comment: @geertjanknapen also delete vendor folder won't delete files created in resourses / controllers ...

Comment: You can look here to see what files are created when you run with the `vue` stack option, if you want to delete them manually;
https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/1.x/src/Console/InstallsInertiaStacks.php#L15